# Why TransparentBlt function cannot work on a bmp picture with a black background?

Tags: c++, winapi, win32gui

I want to embed a picture with a black background in another picture of green woods. But I discovered the TransparentBlt() function cannot work. While I embed a picture with a white background, the function works properly. Why?

This is my code:

```
HBITMAP hbm = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, L"bg.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 1280, 720, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
HBITMAP hbm3 = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, L"character3.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 535, 650, LR_LOADFROMFILE)
HBITMAP hbm5 = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, L"character5.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 276, 418, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
HDC memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);  
SelectObject(memdc, hbm);       
BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, memdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);  
SelectObject(memdc, hbm3);
TransparentBlt(hdc, 40, 60, 506, 650, memdc, 0, 0, 535, 650, RGB(0,0,0));
SelectObject(memdc, hbm5);
TransparentBlt(hdc, 40, 60, 506, 650, memdc, 0, 0, 276, 418,RGB(253,253,253));
```

This is a failure result:

[image]

This is a success result:

[image]

Comment: `TransparentBlt()` simply doesn't support black as a transparent color. Use a different color. Or else use a separate mask bitmap to specify the transparent areas so you can AND out the background bitmap and then OR the overlay bitmap on top of it.

Comment: Another alternative would be to use per-pixel alpha transparency. For that to work you'd need to pass the `LR_CREATEDIBSECTION` flag into the `LoadImage` calls, and then use [`AlphaBlend`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-alphablend) instead. This allows you to encode transparency in the source image independent from the pixel color. Keep in mind that the GDI expects premultiplied image data (i.e. the color channels must be multiplied with the alpha value).

Comment: Or use per-pixel alpha by just using a library. FreeImage is pretty simple to use in conjunction with Win32, for example.

Answer (score 0):

To make the black background transparent, you need to create a new compatible DC like this:

```
HDC memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
HDC memdc2 = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
SelectObject(memdc, hbm3);
TransparentBlt(memdc2, 40, 60, 506, 650, memdc, 0, 0, 535, 650, RGB(0,0,0));
BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, memdc2, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
```

Although not sure why, this works on my computer.